# Electron: Wait for a message from renderer process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

### Scenario:

I have an Electron app. I also have a main process and a renderer process (which is a React component). There are a number of questions available for the main process. The main process sends these questions to the renderer process one question at a time. Once the renderer process receives a question, it displays it to the user and the user needs to answer that question and hit submit. Once, submit is hit, the answer is sent back to the main process for further processing after which the main process sends the next question and so on until all the questions are answered.

### Current state:

I am able to send the question to the renderer, but I don't know how to wait for the answer.

### Code to illustrate the idea:

Main:

```
    // Get all questions
    const questions = [...];
    // Iterate through questions
    for (const question of questions) {
        // Send question
        window.getAllWindows()[0].webContents.send('question', { question: question });

        // TODO: Wait for answer
        // TODO: do something with answer
    }
```

**Note: The program cannot continue until all the questions are answered.**

I am aware that JavaScript is single-threaded and cannot block the execution of the code, which is why I am having difficulty implementing this.

Comment: You don't need to wait by processing the answers once they're sent by the renderer process. Once processed, you can send the next questions to the renderer and then re-start the whole cycle. That's basically the whole idea of making IPC event-driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really after is an Electron method similar to `ipcRenderer.invoke` but instead of "render to main and back
again", you want "main to render and back again".

There is no real "wait" command one can easily implement in this instance unless you start using promises and a `while`
or `do / while` loop.

Instead of iterating over the questions like that, how about comparing the number of answers received to the total
number of questions. When all the questions have been asked / answers received, then move on to the next step in your
application.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
'use strict';

const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
    askQuestion(); // <--- Ask first question upon window creation
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

const questions = [
    {'question': 'Question 1'},
    {'question': 'Question 2'},
    {'question': 'Question 3'}
]

let answers = [];

electronIpcMain.on('submitAnswer', (event, answer) => {
    // Process answer.
    answers.push(answer);

    if (answers.length < questions.length) {
        askQuestion();
    } else {
        console.log('All questions answered');
        console.log(answers);
    }
})

function askQuestion() {
    window.webContents.send('askQuestion', questions[answers.length].question);
}
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electronAPI', {
        // From main to render
        askQuestion: (question) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('askQuestion', question)
        },
        // From render to main
        submitAnswer: (answer) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('submitAnswer', answer)
        }
    });
```

---

`index.html` (main process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Question</h2>
            <div id="question"></div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Answer</h2>
            <textarea id="answer" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </body>

    <script>
        let questionField = document.getElementById('question');
        let answerField = document.getElementById('answer');

        window.electronAPI.askQuestion((event, question) => {
            answerField.value = '';
            questionField.innerText = question;
        })

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.electronAPI.submitAnswer(answerField.value);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I did something similar, but using an iterator for the questions.